# XNA with SQLite

Tags: xna, databases

Does anyone have experience using SQLite with XNA?

Or using any other DB with XNA?

Comment: I think you mean SQLite?? Might want to update the spelling (though Google will find it right) so people are aware.

Comment: For sure using SQLite isn't a good choice when it comes to huge amounts of data: e.g. MMOs.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the appropriate answers are 'Yes', 'No but I used this' and 'No' Do we have a specific question to answer here???

Comment: Just a comment: Most games are better off loading their data all into RAM in which case the file storage format doesn't matter too much.

Comment: -1, because like @James says, there isn't a question here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLight does work with XNA, just don't expect any store procedures or functions.  Any flat file will work to store data (XML, JSON etc). I prefer XML, though if I was using lots of data I would switch to SQLite

Answer (score 5):

You should have no issues Accessing SQLite from a Windows XNA Game. On Windows, XNA Project is just like any other project and you can do anything that C# can do. On Xbox or WP7 this isn't completely the case; however, there is also a C# version of SQLite written to run on fully managed environment (Xbox, WP7): see the ZMan's post here: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/47127/282261.aspx